# How can I make API gateway only available to my ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I deployed a lambda to AWS and created an api gateway to access it. I don't want the API gateway to be public because the lambda is only called from one of my ec2 instance. What is the best way to configure it to secure this API? My ec2 instance needs public IP address since I have DNS configure route pointing to it.

Comment: Side-question: If the Lambda function is only called from a single EC2 instance, why did you choose to use API Gateway instead of calling the Lambda `invoke()` function directly?

Comment: I am not aware about `invoke` function. How can I call this from ec2 instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only using the AWS Lambda function from a single Amazon EC2 instance, there is no need to use API Gateway. (API Gateway is normally used to expose an API to a large number of users.)

You can instead **invoke an AWS Lambda function directly:**

- You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) by calling [`aws lambda invoke`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html)
- You can also use an AWS SDK from a programming language such as [Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html), [Java](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/invoking-aws-lambda-functions-from-java/) and [Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html)

Comment: can `ec2` and `lambda` be in different region?

Comment: Yes. When you invoke a Lambda function, you can specify the region. From the AWS CLI, you would use `--region`. In an SDK, you can specify the region when creating the Lambda client object.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Private API in Amazon API Gateway,
This will secure your API Gateway and make it accessible only to the resources within your VPC.
It can be further secured using the Security group and Resource Policy for a Private API.

You will need to create an Endpoint to use a Private API Gateway though.

**Detailed setup -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html

Comment: Does my ec2 instance need to be in the private `VPC` as well? If yes, how can I access to ec2 instance?

Comment: To access the Private API Gateway, your EC2 will need to be in the same VPC as of the API Gateway. EC2's subnet will depend on the use case, if it's a Frontend then Public Subnet, if it's an API server, then launch in Private subnet, which can be accessed via a Bastion host.